# Losing some formatting when displaying some text using blessed/blessed-contrib

Tags: terminal, text-styling, blessed

I'm using blessed and blessed-contrib to create a terminal based dashboard, and for some of the logs I was going to implement some formatting (bold, italics, underlined, strikethrough, color, etc). And when I try to run a simple test with the below script (which is just a modified blessed-contrib example):

```js
var blessed = require('blessed')
  , contrib = require('blessed-contrib')
  , screen = blessed.screen()
  , log = contrib.log(
      { fg: "grey"
      , label: 'Server Log'      
      , height: "20%"
      , tags: true      
      , border: {type: "line", fg: "cyan"} })
    
screen.append(log)

var i = 0
setInterval(function() {
  log.log(new Date().toISOString() + " \x1B[1mBold\x1B[0m, \x1B[3mItalic\x1B[0m, \x1B[4mUnderline\x1B[0m, \x1B[9mStrikethrough\x1B[0m, \x1B[31mRed font\x1B[0m")}, 500)

screen.render()
```

The output I get shows that only the bold and underline formatting seem to work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlQJs.png)

Just to be sure it wasn't some limitation with my terminal or some issue with NodeJS, I created a script with just the following:

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString() + " \x1B[1mBold\x1B[0m, \x1B[3mItalic\x1B[0m, \x1B[4mUnderline\x1B[0m, \x1B[9mStrikethrough\x1B[0m, \x1B[31mRed font\x1B[0m")
```

And it worked just fine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuniD.png)

I tried using some libraries to add styling to the text (eg: chalk), but those had the same issue.

Is there a way to use such font modifiers in blessed/blessed-contrib components?